# Responsive table design: Make click() expand tr using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, html-table

I want the tables on my webpage to behave responsively. The idea is for them to automatically be represented as accordions as soon as the page width is below a certain threshold. I pulled the example code for the accordion from [this](http://www.freizeitler.de/2014/08/19/usability-und-content-strategien-eine-tabelle-im-responsive-web-design/) page.

My problem now is that the entire table row is turned into a button which triggers the respective folding/unfolding. How can I rewire the `js` in order to make the `<i>` element responsible for receiving the click-event instead of the `<tr>` element?

The reason for which I want this behavior is quite simple: My table contains several `input` elements which this point cannot be used anymore as the table would fold back as soon as any of these inputs is clicked.

This is my attempt. However, it fold/unfolds every row instead of only the one clicked by the user:

```
trAcc.find('i').click(function () {
    if (trAcc.hasClass('accordion-opened')) {
        trAcc
          .animate({ maxHeight: '50px' }, 200)
          .removeClass('accordion-opened');

        $(this).text('+');

    } else {
        trAcc
          .animate({ maxHeight: '1000px' }, 400)
          .addClass('accordion-opened');

        $(this).text('-');
    }
});
```

Here is the original [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Freizeitler/fzJLZ/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=fzJLZ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I am new to `jQuery` I currently do not know much about the API. However, I just stumbled upon the [parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) method. Using it the problem gets quite easy and my solution boils down to this:

```
trAcc.find('i').click(function () {
    if ($(this).parent('tr').hasClass('accordion-opened')) {
        $(this).parent('tr')
          .animate({ maxHeight: '50px' }, 200)
          .removeClass('accordion-opened');

        $(this).text('+');

    } else {
        $(this).parent('tr')
          .animate({ maxHeight: '1000px' }, 400)
          .addClass('accordion-opened');

        $(this).text('-');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified your original jsFiddle code a little like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fzJLZ/76/).

```
trAcc.append('<i class="icon-accordion">+</i>');
    $('.icon-accordion').on('click', function (e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('accordion-opened')) {
            $(this)
                .parent()
                .animate({maxHeight: '60px'}, 200)
                .removeClass('accordion-opened')
                .end()
                .text('+');
        } else {
            $(this)
                .parent()
                .animate({maxHeight: '1000px'}, 400)
                .addClass('accordion-opened')
                .end()
                .text('-');
               }
       });
```